# When trying to connect to office 365 using Connect-PnPOnline with PowerShell Azure function I get an exception

Tags: function, azure, authentication, office365

When trying to connect to office 365 using  Connect-PnPOnline with  PowerShell Azure function I get an exception , while doing the same from local machine it works fine.

$securepw = ConvertTo-SecureString $env:PW -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($env:USER, $securepw)
$spo = "https://.sharepoint.com/sites/tt"
Connect-PnPOnline   -Url  $spo -Credentials $credentials

--
    Using recent version 
     explicitly import PnP-PowerShell cmdlets

```
Import-Module
```

"D:\home\site\wwwroot\modules\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline\3.9.1905.3\SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline.psd1" -verbose

--
    Exception:

```
2019-05-29T23:09:27.958 [Error] ERROR: Method not found: 'System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.String, System.String)'.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Rpc.RpcException : Result: ERROR: Method not found: 'System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.String, System.String)'.
Exception: Method not found: 'System.Runtime.Remoting.ObjectHandle System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.String, System.String)'.
Stack:    at OfficeDevPnP.Core.Diagnostics.Log.InitializeLogger()
   at OfficeDevPnP.Core.Diagnostics.Log.Error(String source, String message, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContextExtensions.ExecuteQueryImplementation(ClientRuntimeContext clientContext, Int32 retryCount, Int32 delay, String userAgent)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContextExtensions.ExecuteQueryRetry(ClientRuntimeContext clientContext, Int32 retryCount, Int32 delay, String userAgent)
   at SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.SPOnlineConnectionHelper.InstantiateSPOnlineConnection(Uri url, PSCredential credentials, PSHost host, Boolean currentCredentials, Int32 minimalHealthScore, Int32 retryCount, Int32 retryWait, Int32 requestTimeout, String tenantAdminUrl, Boolean disableTelemetry, Boolean skipAdminCheck, ClientAuthenticationMode authenticationMode)
   at SharePointPnP.PowerShell.Commands.Base.ConnectOnline.ProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.Cmdlet.DoProcessRecord()
   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
```

---

References:

1. I was trying to apply the following blog:
   http://johnliu.net/blog/2018/4/run-any-pnp-powershell-in-one-azurefunction-from-microsoft-flow
2. It seems to me this exception happened recently to other.
   https://twitter.com/erwinvanhunen/status/1095413544810627074